# docker-compose build: Retry a step in case it fails for x times?

Tags: docker, build, docker-compose

Due to to partly bad internet in our company we are having issues with building our containers constantly. Lets assume we have our php-fpm container which requires a lot of additional software and has about 60 build steps.

Now when doing `docker-compose build --no-cache php-fpm` the process quite often quits when e.g. doing `apt-get update` or installing a certain library.

Output is like this:

```
Step 29/56 : RUN apt-get update     && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install wkhtmltopdf
 ---> Running in 7ec583e71349

[...]

Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libdouble-conversion1 amd64 3.1.0-3
       Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libpcre2-16-0 amd64 10.32-5
  Could not resolve 'deb.debian.org' 

[.....]

ERROR: Service 'php-fpm' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install wkhtmltopdf' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

So I wonder if there is a possibility to tell docker to try a step or even certain steps for like three times before quitting the build process?

Comment: If you don't use `--no-cache` here, Docker will restart where it left off (assuming any files you `COPY` in haven't changed).  You should pretty much never need `--no-cache`; why do you have it here?

Comment: @DavidMaze Sometimes we had issues with the cache. But after using --no-cache once it might already be cleared? Because then after the first failed build I could remove it.

Comment: I'm curious about this as well. We have a step calling `bundle install` in our Dockerfile where it fails spuriously, and it doesn't have retry logic of its own.

Comment: Same. I have a dockerfile that sometimes fails on dnf install step saying it cannot verify peer certs. Rerunning the build works 100 percent of the time. I think it's the company firewall causing intermittent problems.